# Double group by with max date

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, max

I've been having a look around am wondering how I can do a double group by. I have this `fees` table:

| name | end_date | last_check | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 2019-01-01 | 2020-10-11 | 42 |
| bob | 2019-01-01 | 2020-11-25 | 41.45 |
| bob | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-20 | 24.32 |
| bob | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-03 | 29.30 |
| sam | 2019-01-01 | 2020-10-11 | 27.23 |
| sam | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-20 | 23.23 |
| sam | 2020-01-01 | 2020-12-27 | 320.3 |
| sam | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-03 | 320.3 |
| bill | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 28.23 |

I want to first group by the `name`. Then group by the `end_date` but only select the most recent row based on the `last_check`. So my desired output would be:

| name | end_date | last_check | fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bob | 2019-01-01 | 2020-11-25 | 41.45 |
| bob | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-03 | 29.30 |
| sam | 2019-01-01 | 2020-10-11 | 27.23 |
| sam | 2020-01-01 | 2021-02-03 | 320.3 |
| bill | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 28.23 |

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE fees (
 name varchar2(32) not null,
 end_date date not null,
 last_check date not null,
 fee number(5, 2) not null
);

INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('bob', TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), 42);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('bob', TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-11-25','YYYY-MM-DD'), 41.45);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('bob', TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-12-20','YYYY-MM-DD'), 24.32);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('bob', TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2021-02-03','YYYY-MM-DD'), 29.3);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('sam', TO_DATE('2019-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-10-11','YYYY-MM-DD'), 27.23);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('sam', TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-12-20','YYYY-MM-DD'), 23.23);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('sam', TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2020-12-27','YYYY-MM-DD'), 320.3);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('sam', TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2021-02-03','YYYY-MM-DD'), 320.3);
INSERT INTO fees (name, end_date, last_check, fee) VALUES ('bill', TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), TO_DATE('2021-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'), 28.23);
```

My attempt:

```
SELECT name, end_date, max(last_check), fee
from fees
GROUP BY name, end_date, fee
```

Comment: do you have an id for that table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: @PM77-1 I have already tried that and it did not work. That was actually the exact question I went to to try it out.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli No

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov if you don't have ids for your tables, you will be resolve a lot of problems of your own -self stick on the bike-

Comment: There are several solutions there that would've worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way is using row_number()!

If you need build SQLs frequently, please, learn about "partition by".. its change your work!

```
select
   a.*
from
   (
      select
         f.*,
         row_number() over(partition by f.name, f.end_date order by f.last_check desc) as rn
      from
         fees f
   ) a where a.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1. You understand what he needs (I think)

Comment: Seriously, your life will be change learning about row_number(), dense_rank(), partition by with ordery BY (try SUM() with partition by... its magic hehehe)
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

Another one to keep in your arsenal. It might not be as performant, but I find it more descriptive of the intent

```
select distinct 
       name, 
       end_date, 
       max(last_check) over (partition by name, end_date), 
       first_value(fee) over (partition by name, end_date order by last_check desc)
from fees;
```